# SharePoint Rest API to count files according to current user's permission

Tags: rest, sharepoint

Currently I am using a REST API see below to count files in SharePoint library, but how to count according to current logged in user's permission

```
var libUrl = appWebURL + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('" + e.DepLibName + "')/itemcount?@target='" + SPHostUrl + "'";
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more on `count according to current login user's permission`.

Comment: Hi Rohit,Using my code will return the number of items in doc library(e.DepLibName) of all files, what I am trying to do is to get the number of files that current user has permission in one document library.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the method you're using is it only returns the value of the @ItemCount attribute of the List/Library object itself - it's not actually querying the item count based on the permissions of the currently logged in user.

You should switch to the ListData.svc, which *does* apply security trimming to its response. Ex.

```
appWebURL + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + LibraryName +"/$count"
```

This will return the number of items in the List/Library that the currently logged in user has access to, and not the number of items total.